# How to install Ubuntu 24.04 pre-release on WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, 24.04

Even though 24.04 is not released yet, it seems WSL images for 24.04 already exists: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/wsl/noble/current/

But how can I install it?

Comment: Questions about pre-release software are off-topic in AskUbuntu. We will begin to answer questions about 24.04 when it is released. Many other venues answer questions about pre-release.

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: You can use the development version of Ubuntu WSL by searching for 'Ubuntu (Preview)' on the Microsoft Store. It ships with Ubuntu 24.04.

See here: https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9P7BDVKVNXZ6?hl=es-es&gl=US
And the docs: https://canonical-ubuntu-wsl.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/reference/distributions/

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, Download and extract the gz file https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/wsl/noble/current/ubuntu-noble-wsl-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz
so it looks like `ubuntu-noble-wsl-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar` (do not extract the tar file, only extract the gz file) then start powershell as admin and run

```
wsl --import Ubuntu-24.04-beta C:\wsl\ubuntu_24_04_beta ubuntu-noble-wsl-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar
```

where `C:\wsl\ubuntu_24_04_beta` is the folder where you want the distro to be installed., aka the folder where it puts the virtual disk file. then you can launch it with

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-24.04-beta
```

or make it the default distro with

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu-24.04-beta
```

and then

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-24.04-beta bash -c 'cat /etc/*release*'
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch)"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch)"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04 (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
(...)
```